# Разблокировка кнопки при выборе Radiobutton

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть три радиобаттона, нужно чтоб кнопка была выключена, если ни один из них не выбран.

```
radioButton1.Checked = radioButton2.Checked = radioButton3.Checked = false;
if (radioButton1.Checked == true || radioButton2.Checked == true || radioButton1.Checked == true) 
{
    button1.Enabled = true;
}

else
{
   button1.Enabled = false;
}
```

Вроде должно работать, но не работает. Блокирует кнопку намертво.

Comment: Вы ничего не путаете? Смысл радиобаттонов как раз в том, чтобы один из них всегда был выбран.

Comment: А почему это должио работать иначе, если Вы сбрасываете все 3 в false `radioButton1.Checked = radioButton2.Checked = radioButton3.Checked = false;`

Comment: это просто строка сброса, код должен активировать кнопку при изменении значения в true, то есть активации пользователем баттона, этого не происходит

Comment: здесь все изначально неверно. если этот код стоит в обработчике события отметки радиобатона, тогда он никогда не заработает как Вам надо. вы сначала все радиобатоны отмечаете как НЕ отмеченые, а потом среди них ищите, что же отмечено. Смотрите мой ответ, хоть он и на WPF, но это просто и понятно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделайте так, чтобы был один обработчик для всех radiobutton'ов при их check'е
пример кода:

```
private void radioButton1_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    button.IsEnabled = true;
}
```

Код окна:

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
   <Button x:Name="button" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Content="Кнопка" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="28" Width="381" Margin="15" IsEnabled="False"/>
   <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
      <RadioButton Name="radioButton1" Margin="5" GroupName="RB" Checked="radioButton1_Checked">RadioButton 1</RadioButton>
      <RadioButton Name="radioButton2" Margin="5" GroupName="RB" Checked="radioButton1_Checked">RadioButton 2</RadioButton>
      <RadioButton Name="radioButton3" Margin="5" GroupName="RB" Checked="radioButton1_Checked">RadioButton 3</RadioButton>
   </StackPanel>
</DockPanel>
```

Тогда, при отметке любого RadioButton'a - кнопка `button` станет активной

Comment: хэш тэг  си шарп стоит, проблему решил, спасибо всем.

Answer (score 1):

Если не принципиально управлять состоянием кнопки на стороне сервера, то можно обойтись джаваскриптом.

**HTML**

```
<head>
    <title>Test Radio Buttons</title>
    <script type="text/jscript">
        function EnableSubmit() {
            var btn = document.getElementById("button1");
            btn.disabled = false;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="title radiobar">
        <h3>Radio buttons:</h3>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="testRadio" id="radioButton1" onclick="EnableSubmit()" />
            radioButton1
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="testRadio" id="radioButton2" onclick="EnableSubmit()" />
            radioButton2
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="testRadio" id="radioButton3" onclick="EnableSubmit()" />
            radioButton3
        </label>
    </div>
    <p>
        <button id="button1" disabled="disabled">OK</button>
    </p>
</body>
```

Если хотите управлять кнопкой на стороне сервера, то после изменения состояния каждого радиобаттона нужно заново отправлять пользователю страницу (свойства `AutoPostBack` установлено в `true`). Без этого никакие изменения на сервере он не увидит, потому что видит в браузере скомпилированную страницу.

**Файл .aspx:**

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="title radiobar">
            <h3>Radio buttons:</h3>
            <label>
                <asp:RadioButton runat="server" GroupName="testRadio" ID="radioButton1" AutoPostBack="true" />
                radioButton1
            </label>
            <label>
                <asp:RadioButton runat="server" GroupName="testRadio" ID="radioButton2" AutoPostBack="true" />
                radioButton2
            </label>
            <label>
                <asp:RadioButton runat="server" GroupName="testRadio" ID="radioButton3" AutoPostBack="true" />
                radioButton3
            </label>
        </div>
        <p>
            <asp:Button ID="button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" Enabled="false" />
        </p>
    </form>
</body>
```

**Файл .aspx.cs:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack) // если это первая загрузка страницы
            {
                radioButton1.Checked = radioButton2.Checked = radioButton3.Checked = false;
            }
            else // если повторная загрузка после отправки на сервер по нажатию на радиобаттон
            {
                if (radioButton1.Checked == true || radioButton2.Checked == true || radioButton3.Checked == true)
                {
                    button1.Enabled = true;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: это не javascript и не html, а C#) или исправляйте ответ или удалите

Comment: Дополнила. Нигде не было сказано, что нужно управлять состоянием именно на стороне сервера.

Comment: нигде и не сказано что это ASP.NET

Comment: То есть мы зря пытаемся помочь автору, который ничего толком не объяснил.

Comment: вариантов не так и много. WPF, ASP, WinForm. и все что надо уже есть в ответах, не по крайней мере - можно разобраться